# how to fix size of 9 patch using xml. Image view is not a part of any xml

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have got an Overlay. inside that we use to drop one bitmap image. Now this image is changed with 9 patch image. After putting new 9 patch image it stretches all teh way. I tried to fix the size of 9 patch using code something like this. But it did not work. Here scrollbar_bg is 9 patch image. below code is inside selector.

```
<item  android:drawable="@drawable/scrollbar_indicator" >

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
        android:width="90dp"
        android:height="209dp"/>

        <padding
        android:left="37dp"
        android:right="43dp"/>
    </shape>

</item>
```

Can any one help me in this regard?

Comment: Very unclear. Do you need a stretchable (9 patch) image or a fixed one?

Comment: I have to use new 9 patch image . But its height and width should be fix and should be same as old bit map image.

Comment: `I have to use new 9 patch image . But its height and width should be fix` It's a **nonsense**: 9 patches are meant to be stretched, not to have a fixed size.